# Read multiple message resources under different packages having same/different name in on go?

Tags: java, resources, bundle, resourcebundle

Read multiple message resources having same/different name, under different packages, in a jar in on go?

let's suppose my jar xyz.jar structure is as follow:
project structure:

```
src|main|resources
              |pkg1|message1.properties
              |pkg2|message2.properties
              ...
              |pkg3|message1.properties
```

These resources under different packages are being generated dynamically through maven goals. What I want here, load all resource bundles and maintain at single place along with package name. I don't want to hard code these packages in my code, even don't want to change my code when new files are being added dynamically.
Any help, much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If locating these property files dynamically is what you need, you can use apache.commons.io FileUtils for that.

```
String[] s = {"properties"};
File f = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("./").getFile());

Collection<File> o = FileUtils.listFiles(f, s, true);
for (File file : o) {
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

And you can move files to the required location with Files.move method.